# MySQLdump-import into DB with different Charset: from unicode_520_ci to utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql

Need to rework a db-dump that comes with more than 2000 lines in order to fit my MySQL-DB.  the difference is the Charset. i need to go from

COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
to
CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

how to do this correctly for the whole dump?

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.23-23, for Linux (x86_64)
-- Host: localhost    Database: s_wp868
-- Server version   5.7.23-23
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!50717 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rocksdb_has_p_s_session_variables FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'performance_schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'session_variables' */;
/*!50717 SET @rocksdb_get_is_supported = IF (@rocksdb_has_p_s_session_variables, 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @rocksdb_is_supported FROM performance_schema.session_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME=\'rocksdb_bulk_load\'', 'SELECT 0') */;
/*!50717 PREPARE s FROM @rocksdb_get_is_supported */;
/*!50717 EXECUTE s */;
/*!50717 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s */;
/*!50717 SET @rocksdb_enable_bulk_load = IF (@rocksdb_is_supported, 'SET SESSION rocksdb_bulk_load = 1', 'SET @rocksdb_dummy_bulk_load = 0') */;
/*!50717 PREPARE s FROM @rocksdb_enable_bulk_load */;
/*!50717 EXECUTE s */;
/*!50717 DEALLOCATE PREPARE s */;





DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wpsu_actionscheduler_actions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `wpsu_actionscheduler_actions` (
  `action_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hook` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `scheduled_date_gmt` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `scheduled_date_local` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `args` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `schedule` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
  `group_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attempts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_attempt_gmt` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_attempt_local` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `claim_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `extended_args` varchar(8000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`action_id`),
  KEY `hook` (`hook`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `scheduled_date_gmt` (`scheduled_date_gmt`),
  KEY `args` (`args`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `last_attempt_gmt` (`last_attempt_gmt`),
  KEY `claim_id_status_scheduled_date_gmt` (`claim_id`,`status`,`scheduled_date_gmt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wpsu_actionscheduler_actions`
--

LOCK TABLES `wpsu_actionscheduler_actions` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wpsu_actionscheduler_actions` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `wpsu_actionscheduler_actions` (`action_id`, `hook`, `status`, `scheduled_date_gmt`, `scheduled_date_local`, `args`, `schedule`, `group_id`, `attempts`, `last_attempt_gmt`, `last_attempt_local`, `claim_id`, `extended_args`) VALUES (7,'action_scheduler/migration_hook','complete','2022-02-24 18:34:17','2022-02-24 18:34:17','[]','O:30:\"ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\":2:{s:22:\"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp\";i:1645727657;s:41:\"\0ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\0timestamp\";i:1645727657;}',1,1,'2022-02-24 18:34:53','2022-02-24 18:34:53',0,NULL),(8,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:40:15','2022-02-24 18:40:15',0,NULL),(9,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:40:15','2022-02-24 18:40:15',0,NULL),(10,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:41:03','2022-02-24 18:41:03',0,NULL),(11,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:41:03','2022-02-24 18:41:03',0,NULL),(12,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:41:03','2022-02-24 18:41:03',0,NULL),(13,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:41:03','2022-02-24 18:41:03',0,NULL),(14,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:41:03','2022-02-24 18:41:03',0,NULL),(15,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:41:03','2022-02-24 18:41:03',0,NULL),(16,'woocommerce_admin/stored_state_setup_for_products/async/run_remote_notifications','complete','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','[]','O:28:\"ActionScheduler_NullSchedule\":0:{}',0,1,'2022-02-24 18:41:03','2022-02-24 18:41:03',0,NULL),(17,'woocommerce_run_update_callback','complete','2022-03-15 18:00:27','2022-03-15 18:00:27','{\"update_callback\":\"wc_update_630_create_product_attributes_lookup_table\"}','O:30:\"ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\":2:{s:22:\"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp\";i:1647367227;s:41:\"\0ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\0timestamp\";i:1647367227;}',2,1,'2022-03-15 18:00:47','2022-03-15 18:00:47',0,NULL),(18,'woocommerce_run_update_callback','complete','2022-03-15 18:00:28','2022-03-15 18:00:28','{\"update_callback\":\"wc_update_630_db_version\"}','O:30:\"ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\":2:{s:22:\"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp\";i:1647367228;s:41:\"\0ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\0timestamp\";i:1647367228;}',2,1,'2022-03-15 18:00:48','2022-03-15 18:00:48',0,NULL),(19,'woocommerce_update_db_to_current_version','complete','2022-03-15 18:00:29','2022-03-15 18:00:29','{\"version\":\"6.3.1\"}','O:30:\"ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\":2:{s:22:\"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp\";i:1647367229;s:41:\"\0ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\0timestamp\";i:1647367229;}',2,1,'2022-03-15 18:00:48','2022-03-15 18:00:48',0,NULL),(20,'woocommerce_run_product_attribute_lookup_regeneration_callback','complete','2022-03-15 18:00:48','2022-03-15 18:00:48','[]','O:30:\"ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\":2:{s:22:\"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp\";i:1647367248;s:41:\"\0ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\0timestamp\";i:1647367248;}',2,1,'2022-03-15 18:00:48','2022-03-15 18:00:48',0,NULL),(21,'wc-admin_import_customers','complete','2022-03-15 18:05:24','2022-03-15 18:05:24','[1]','O:30:\"ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\":2:{s:22:\"\0*\0scheduled_timestamp\";i:1647367524;s:41:\"\0ActionScheduler_SimpleSchedule\0timestamp\";i:1647367524;}',3,1,'2022-03-15 18:06:48','2022-03-15 18:06:48',0,NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wpsu_actionscheduler_actions` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I need to rework the dataset - to fit the db here - which actually works with another charset  - see below

```
MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.33, for Linux (x86_64)
Host: localhost    Database: fsj
-- Server version   5.5.33
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
-- Table structure for table `wp_postmeta`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_postmeta`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
-- Dumping data for table `wp_postmeta`

LOCK TABLES `wp_postmeta` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VALUES (1,2,'_wp_page_template','default'),(2,3,'_wp_page_template','default');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Well i think that have to rework all the following statements

```
utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

with the following `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

in other words:  i try to replace all

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

to

```
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

... in the whole DB-Dump.

Conclusio: I did this - but i still have issues. How to treat the db-dump correct to get it into my MySQL-Db?!

Comment: replace only the collation the charset is already utfmb4

Comment: hello dear nbk - so i only have to do a minor change!? I do not have to touch the utfmb4 at all.  I try to understand where to change the dataset (the dump). ?

Comment: You said, "I still have issues" -- what are the issues? I.e. did you get an error? What was the error?

Comment: @zero you need only to change the collation that enough for your purpose

Comment: hello dear @BillKarwin hello dear nbk - many thanks for the reply: i have had various areas where the term =utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci appeared. At the beginning i was not sure how to rework the whole dump and how to start.  I will do my best and try to apply all the necessary changes tomorrow in office. Many thanks for all your tipps.